# How to include a php file in a Javascript POST method

Tags: php, post, get, server-side-includes

I have a php script which calculates something very very long.

It is called from a js file and I want to call it from another php file in addition to  calling it from the js file.

The file is called strategy.server.php and it is build like so

```
 <?php
    include_once("../config.php");
    include_once("../class/simulator.class.php");

    $simulator = new Simulator();
    $SPOT = $_GET["strikePrice"];
    $INTEREST = $_GET["interestRate"] / 100;
    $VOLATILITY = $_GET["volatility"] / 100;
    $REMAININGDAYS = $_GET["remainingDays"] / 365;

    header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
    header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . "GMT");
    header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");

    if(!empty($_GET['mycase']))
    {
        switch($_GET['mycase'])
////calculations... 
            $data['totalMargin'];  
           echo json_encode($data);
```

I am trying to us the same file to calculate for different parameters (in a loop).
So I thought about using a an include and posting the parameters like so :

```
$params         = "some params...";
$params     .=  "strikePrice=".$data["strikePrice"].
        "&volatility=".$data["volatility"].
        "&remainingDays=".$data["remainingDays"].
        "&interestRate=".$data["interestRate"].
        "&commission="."7".//$data["commission"].
        "&profitDays="."7";//$data["profitDays"];

include("server/strategy.server.php?" .$params);
json_decode($data);
echo $data['totalMargin'];
```

but it gives an error:
`Warning: include(server/strategy.server.php?mycase=1&rangeMin=0&rangeMax=0&strikePrice=1078&volatility=24&remainingDays=51&interestRate=2.5&commission=7&profitDays=7)
  [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\s-maof-vb\PRO\functions_alarms.php on line 86`

If I include the file with the parameters, it loads up (but with no parameters..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Including a PHP file inserts all the operations from within the file into the current PHP file being executed, so any parameters defined in scope are accessible from within the code.

For example if I had a file called `echo.php` with the contents:

```
<?php
echo $test."\n";
```

And included it within another file:

```
<?php
$test= "hello";
include("echo.php");
$test = "world";
include("echo.php");
```

The result would be:

```
hello
world
```

So parameters to included files are not passed using HTTP GET method, but just by what is defined in scope. Also, get parameters to the end of a filename in unix will result in the filesystem looking for the entire string on disk.

For the above example, the file would compile out to be:

```
<?php
$test= "hello";
echo $test."\n";
$test = "world";
echo $test."\n";
```

Therefore in your case, you may want to edit the `strategy.server.php` script to check first whether data is passed in a params array and then default to GET:

```
if(empty($params)){
   $params = $_GET; 
}
// filter params for user input;
```

Comment: hi paul, thanks for the reply. as you can see the problem is more basic . The script is unable to load the file in the first place!

Comment: ah ok, where is the file relative to the file being included? if you take of the get parameters does it work? `include(server/strategy.server.php);`

Comment: yes. I am trying now to set the _GET variable befoe including the function like so: $_GET['mycase'] = 1;

Comment: I guess that is one way to do it!

Answer (score 0):

The include function doesn't accept parameters in a way HTTP does. Also, what you are trying to do isn't best practice, because it includes the same file multiple times. You have to create a for- or while-loop going through the array of $data values.

If you still want this functionality I suggest using the [cURL library](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php) or [file_get_contents()](https://www.php.net/file_get_contents) to call the script (instead of including).